# Apagar labels criadas programaticamente

Tags: c#, winforms, label, eventos-do-mouse

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação para mapeamento que usa labels para dar nome ás diferentes salas de um edificio.

O codigo que uso para criar as labels é o seguinte:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Left = l.Left;
            l.Top = l.Top;
            l.BringToFront();
            l.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            l.Text = (listBox1.SelectedItem).ToString();
            l.BringToFront();
            l.Visible = true;
            l.Name = "label_";
            // Add whatever other properties you deem important

            l.Size = new Size(250, 20);

            this.Controls.Add(l);
            {
                l.BringToFront();
            }

            Controls.Add(l);
            ControlExtension.Draggable(l, true);
}
```

Eu tentei usar o seguinte para remover o que queria, mas apenas remove a label inicial e nao as que sao criadas em runtime:

```
private void l_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(l);
}
```

A minha ultima tentativa foi:

```
public void Label_Killer(Label label)
{
    label.Dispose();
}
```

para depois chamar na criaçao de uma label nova mas nao sei como proceder...

Portanto eu venho aqui perguntar:
Há alguma maneira de remover **qualquer label** por double click?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar o evento `DoubleClick` nas labels que cria. 
Após criada a `label`, use o código:

```
l.DoubleClick += L_DoubleClick;
```

E crie o evento:

```
private void L_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(((Label)sender));
}
```